# How do you remove seconds and milliseconds from a date time string in python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

How I can convert a date in format `"2013-03-15 05:14:51.327"` to `"2013-03-15 05:14"`, i.e. removing the seconds and milliseconds. I don't think there is way in Robot frame work. Please let me know if any one have a solution for this in python.

Comment: Is that date a string or a date object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (Thanks Blender!)

```
>>> date = "2013-03-15 05:14:51.327"
>>> newdate = date.rpartition(':')[0]
>>> print newdate
2013-03-15 05:14
```

Comment: I'd use `.rpartition(':')` here. The number of decimal points may change.

Answer (score 0):

In Robotframework the most straightforward way would be to user [`Split String From Right` from the String library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Split%20String%20From%20Right) library:

```
${datestring}=    Set Variable    2019-03-15 05:14:51.327
${parts}=  Split String From Right    ${datestring}    :    max_split=1
# parts is a list of two elements - everything before the last ":", and everything after it
# take the 1st element, it is what we're after
${no seconds}=    Get From List     ${parts}    0
Log    ${no senods}    # 2019-03-15 05:14
```